# passing parameter of boolean type from SSRS to PL/SQL

Tags: reporting-services, types, boolean

Could you please tell me if there is a way to pass a parameter of boolean type from reporting services to PL/SQL?  I tried using data type boolean in PL/SQL and that is not allowing me to create the dataset.

My report has a radio button, asking for the sort order asc or desc.  I was thinking of sorting it from the procedure side.  My report does not have any grouping.  Can I sort the table using this value on the SSRS side itself?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might try if you want to use the parameter value in your SQL statement is have a parameter that you can use to alter the SQL statement. For example, have a string parameter called SortOrder which allows the items (Non-query):

```
Value    Label
--------------------
ASC      Ascending
DESC     Descending
```

Then you can use this to alter your SQL statement. Your SQL statement can be passed as a string so you data source may look something like this:

```
="SELECT * "
&"FROM MyTable "
&"ORDER BY SomeField " & Parameters!SortOrder.Value
```

If you really want to use a radio button, then you could do something like this:

```
="SELECT * "
&"FROM MyTable "
&"ORDER BY SomeField " & IF(Parameters!SortOrder.Value, "ASC", "DESC")
```

Comment: how do you execute this statement? it is not creating me the dataset, fileds are not shown

Comment: If you set the SQL string manually like this you need to either set the fields up manually (in the fields list, right-click and chose Add) or run the SQL once normally to have the fields set up for you, then turn it into a string like above to include your parameters in the SQL

Comment: thanks, that helps, but my report should be able to pass the boolean type parameter value to the PL/SQL stored procedure. its not doing that any way (giving boolen type in pl/sql). is that is possible  by any chance